# Django NoReverseMatch at /project/360c2471-44ff-4d8c-b536-c9da3448c002/ Reverse for 'conversation' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi I am currently facing a problem in redirecting the user to my directs-app.
The `NewConversation` in `directs/views.py` starts a new conversation. It can be clicked in the profile-page `user-profile.html` of the `users`-app. Now I wanna do the same in my `single-project.html` in my `projects`-app. But I am getting the error above. Thanks for your help!

directs/views.py

```
def NewConversation(request, username):
    from_user = request.user
    body = ''
    try:
        to_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except Exception as e:
        return redirect('search-users')
    if from_user != to_user:
        Message.sender_message(from_user, to_user, body)
    return redirect('message')
```

directs/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new/<username>', views.NewConversation, name="conversation"),
]
```

users/models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

users/views.py

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'users/user-profile.html', context)
```

users/user-profile.html

```
          <h2 class="dev__name">{{profile.name}}</h2>
          <img class="avatar avatar--xl dev__avatar" src="{{profile.profile_image.url}}" />
          <a href="{% url 'conversation' profile.user  %}" class="btn profile-edit-btn">Message</a>
```

projects/views.py

```
def project(request, pk):
    projectObj = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'project':projectObj}
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', context)
```

projects/models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

projects/single-project.html

```
<div class="project__tags" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <a href="{% url 'conversation' project.owner.user  %}">Send message</a>
</div>
```

projects.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('project/<str:pk>/', views.project, name='project'),
]
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message/traceback, it should tell you what url was tried and what arguments were used. `Project.owner` is nullable, if it's null then you should handle it and not render a link

Comment: Of course here is the full error: NoReverseMatch at /project/360c2471-44ff-4d8c-b536-c9da3448c002/
Reverse for 'conversation' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['message/new/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\Z']. I´ve added the project-url in my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should also post the entire traceback in your post for more coherence.

Let me start with the error:

`NoReverseMatch at /project/360c2471-44ff-4d8c-b536-c9da3448c002/ Reverse for 'conversation' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['message/new/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\Z']`

Your url for conversation is declared as follows:

```
    path('new/<username>', views.NewConversation, name="conversation"),
]
```

What you should improve here: First you should declare what type of argument you are expecting. `<str:username>` I think you are expecting the string.

Now let's look at the error. You are receiving the argument `''` which is an empty string. The urlpath `conversation` is expecting something that is not an empty string. Why though it is an empty string?

`{% url 'conversation' profile.user  %}` and `{% url 'conversation' project.owner.user  %}`
profile.user will not be what you are expecting as there is no specific representation given to profile.user that django templates knows how to translate. Instead, you are giving it the entire `User` object.
I suggest you to either put there `profile.user.username`, or adding the `___str___` method to your Profile Model.

Something like:

```
def __str__(self):
      return self.username
```

I also recommend to improve your function based views by telling what kind of request are you expecting (here it is a GET I assume).

Also, have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed it to ```profile.user.username``` and it works out.  But ```{% url 'conversation' profile.user  %}``` in user-profile.html also worked out. My question was how to adopt the link to my ```projects/single-project.html```.

Comment: As @Iain pointed out, then you should check whether ```project.owner.user``` exists. If it is null, then ```empty string``` will be returned, thus empty string will be passed that causes your error.
What I wrote, is still valid (because you are more precise with details and you can better know what output should be in certain places, thus a better error management). Therefore, you should first find out why ```project.owner.user``` is null.